# can Classifier that realize a Componet be shared?

Tags: uml

In UML 2.5, it is written : A component acts like a Package for all model elements that are involved in or related to its definition, which should be
either owned or imported explicitly. Typically the Classifiers that realize a Component are owned by it.

So if we need to modeled that a set of classes are used to realize two different components, we have to use something like a packageMerge ?

For example, how to model two components, one dedicated to CRUD operations, the other dedicated to reports, and that these two components use the same set of classes to check access rights ?

I found two solutions, which one is the best for you ?

- model three components, one for the CRUD, one for the reports, one for the access rights and model dependencies between each one. But the classes used to check rights are not a component as UML defines a component.
- model two components and a package rights containing the classes and model that the two components depend of this package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't be too dogmatic in such a case:

[image]

The `String` class is used in both components. Whether you merge it or not is sort of a question for configuration management. So would you link a binary or do you have sources that are being compiled where you can use either component independently. The question should be: who is the reader for this construct? If you have a clear picture you could detail it. Else just leave it open as shown above.